# Keep the displaying of both error and hint if error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I have this code :

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>{{'label.name' | translate }}</mat-label>
        <input
            matInput
            [maxLength]="256"
            type="text"
            formControlName="name"
            [placeholder]="'label.name'| translate"
            [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': form.controls.name.errors }"
            autocomplete="off"
        />

        <mat-hint align="end">{{ form.controls.name?.value | inputLimit }}</mat-hint>
        <mat-error>{{form.controls.name.errors | translate}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Works just fine, the problem is that if I have an error on the input, for example : `Field is empty` is displayed the error message, but the mat-hint is hidden. If no errors the mat-hint is displayed. What can be the cause ? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I solve that in other way :

```
<mat-hint align="end">{{ form.controls.name?.value | inputLimit }}</mat-hint>
<mat-error>
   {{form.controls.name.errors | translateFormError | translate}}
   <mat-hint align="end" class="float-right">{{ form.controls.name?.value | inputLimit }}</mat-hint>
</mat-error>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because you're using ternary operator on mat hint and error gives false in you're ternary operator try to remove ternary

Comment: What do you mean by ternary operator ?

Comment: form.controls.name?.value this ? is ternary operator

Comment: But I need this value.

Comment: you can use without that condition or making more specific condtion

Answer (score -1):

This is the functionality of the material hint it show in the mat form field underline as well as mat-error is also shown at the same place so both get overwrite on each other

To make this work as per your requirement you need to keep the hint outside the **mat-form-field** with the condition.

Thanks.